# How to revert back from GWT-Plugin-2.6.0 to GWT-Plugin-2.4.0?

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, windows-8.1

I have got new system with Windows-8.1-64 bit. When I tried to install GWT plugin in eclipse by default it is downloading GWT-2.6.0 plugin. But, GUI is not displaying in my eclipse. Also, I need to install GWT-2.4.0 plugin in my eclipse. Because, in my production we are using GWT-2.4.0 only. Can you please any one tell me how to install GWT-2.4.0 version plugin in eclipse? I am using eclipse-juno-4.2.

Answer (score 0):

If by “GUI is not displaying” you're talking about the GWT Designer, it is known not to work in 2.6.0. That was temporarily fixed in 2.6.1 and then GWT Designer developers gave up maintaining it so it doesn't work with GWT 2.7.0 either, and probably won't work either with any new GWT version in the foreseeable future.
Moreover, it is possible that GWT Designer doesn't work on a 64bit Windows.

And to get GWT 2.4 with your Google Plugin for Eclipse, just download it from https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/downloads/detail?name=gwt-2.4.0.zip, uncompress it somewhere, and then *add* it to your Eclipse from the Eclipse Settings → Google → Web Toolkit.

---

(but c'mon, 2.4.0 is 3½ years old!)